# GUI library for ThreadX

Tags: user-interface, embedded, threadx

I am working on a ThreadX based embedded system. I want to include a 4.5 inch graphical UI to this device and hence exploring on the possible GUI library / frameworks existing for ThreadX based embedded applications - I am open for both open source and licensed frameworks.

Please help.

Thanks
Arun

Comment: This is not the place for this question.  See item 3 at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

[Azure RTOS GUIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/rtos/guix/overview-guix) is probably your best bet. It's integrated with ThreadX already, has the same license, and comes with lots of examples.

Comment: This question should not be answered, it is clearly off-topic.  Post as a comment by all means.  The point is that Googling "Thread X GUI" would get him that answer.